# How to put the payment method Woocommerce on another page?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

I need to separate the means of payment from the order page to put them on a page dedicated only to that,
I can not find the solution, thanks in advance

Img : https://www.solar-guitars.com/wp-content/themes/solar/assets/img/Capture.PNG

Comment: Try using Yith Woocommerce Plugin

Comment: I have tried a lot of **multistep checkout plugins** free or commercial. But take care as a lot of them doesn't work properly or have annoying bugs. One really work fine on Woocommerce 3+…